# Как сделать смену картинки imageButton при вращении?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, анимация, button

Имеется две картинки и один `ImageButton`. Нужно, чтобы  при нажатии на кнопку, одна картинка менялась на другую с анимацией переворота (как переворот карты), как это реализовать? Разбил анимацию на две составных (каждая поворачивает кнопку на 90 градусов). Как сделать смену изображения между двумя анимациями? Пока что получается смена при начале первой анимации. Знаю, что это неправильно, вот и решил узнать, что делать.

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationY", 0f, 90f);
anim.setDuration(2000);
anim.start();

imageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

ObjectAnimator anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationY", 90f, 180f);
anim2.setDuration(2000);
anim2.setStartDelay(2000);
anim2.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень просто: анимация запускается асинхронно — потому то, что вы поставили строчку с изменением картинки после строчки запуска анимации, ни на что особо не влияет.

Чтобы отследить события при выполнении анимации, нужно добавить слушателя:

```
anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        // Что-то делаем, анимация кончилась
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо,решение действительно оказалось простым,нужно будет почитать про это=)

Comment: @Кирилл запомните с самого начала, что в андроиде почти всё происходит асинхронно. Делается это для того, чтобы интерфейс пользователя не подтормаживал. Впредь старайтесь сами делать всё на коллбэках, где это возможно и где код может влиять на производительность. А если ответ помог решить проблему, поставьте галочку — она чуть левее ответа.